# How to use importmap to pin npm, yarn packages in Rails7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-7, import-maps

I am very excited to use Rails7 especially that we finally get rid of webpacker.
However, today when I tried to try Rails7, I didn't get how to bundle javascript scripts anymore... and there wasn't tutorial there or I just could not find it.

For example, I wanted to import jquery so I ran

```sh
yarn add jquery
```

and then I wrote:

```js
// application.js
//importmap-rails
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "controllers"
import jquery from 'jquery'
```

But it didn't work,
then I read the readme on [importmap-rails](https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails), and I ran

```sh
./bin/importmap pin jquery
```

then it added a line in `config/importmap.rb`

```rb
pin "jquery", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.js"
```

It worked, however, it was not what I expected exactly. I wanted the jquery came from *node_modules/* instead of CDN

How can I achieve that? To import npm packages that I install from yarn/npm?
Or just point out where I can find documents about how to use javascript in Rails7?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```bash
./bin/importmap pin jquery --download
```

will download it.

[Working with JavaScript in Rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html)
(about dealing with JS but little info about importmap)

[importmap-rails](https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails) on GitHub (more info about importmap)

Answer (score 4):

I believe you can manually update your `config/importmap.rb` file to read

```
pin "jquery", to: "./node_modules/jquery"
```

That being said, I believe the design decisions made with importmaps may not include npm or yarn. I believe importmaps represents an alternative method for handling javascript outside of webpacker/yarn/npm.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Although it doesn't work, I appreciate that you pointed out that importmap and npm have different idea to manage the js packages.